# Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and $f'(x)(u)=\sum a_k(x)u_k$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives

Given n real-valued functions $f_1, ... ,f_n$, defined on an open set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ $f(x)=f_1(x)+...f_n(x)$ , assume that the limit exists $\lim_{y \rightarrow x} \frac{f_k(y)-f_k(x)}{y_k-x_k}$ for all $k=1(1)n$ .Call this limit $a_k(x)$ 
Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and $f'(x)(u)=\sum a_k(x)u_k$

From the given condition I can infer that $f_k$ 's are differentiable and hence $f$ is differentiable. But how to prove the rest?

Answer (score 0):

**Rough Reasoning:**

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\left|f(x+h)-f(x)-\displaystyle\sum a_{k}(x)h_{k}\right|}{|h|}&\leq\sum\dfrac{|f_{k}(x+h)-f_{k}(x)-a_{k}(x)h_{k}|}{|h|}\\
&\leq\sum\dfrac{|f_{k}(x+h)-f_{k}(x)-a_{k}(x)h_{k}|}{|h_{k}|}\\
&=\sum\left|\dfrac{f_{k}(x+h)-f_{k}(x)}{h_{k}}-a_{k}(x)\right|\\
&\rightarrow 0,
\end{align*}
where $h=(h_{1},...,h_{n})$.

Comment: Personally I think this exercise is a little problematic, for $y$ being closed to $x$, and $y_{k}=x_{k}$ in this direction, then how the limit is meant to be?

Comment: I don't understand if one of the $h_k 's$ is 0, how will you modify then?

Comment: That's what my comment is concerned about, first of all, how you interpret $\lim_{y\rightarrow x}.../(y_{k}-x_{k})$?

Comment: For $h_k=0$, we have the limit as $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f_k(x+h)-f_k(x)}{h}=a_k(x)$

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand such an interpretation.

Comment: because for $h_k = 0$, take $y=x+h,x=x,y_k=x+h,x_k=x$